# GitHub Copilot Not Auto-Suggesting In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github-copilot

I just installed the GitHub Copilot extension in Visual Studio, and I'm following the setup on GitHub Docs. I got to the point where they tell me to put in some code and I should be getting auto-suggestions, but nothing appears. Anyone know a fix for this?

I enabled GitHub Copilot globally and for C#, but still no auto-suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that I know of.

One use: `//Some thing you want to do`, and then use `Ctrl+Alt+\`.

Another: `//q:Some thing you want to know`, and then use `Ctrl+Alt+\` or `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`.

Comment: When I do this, the GitHub Copilot window opens and just says `Synthesizing 0 solutions`.  It says that no matter what prompt I give it, even when following the tutorials on GitHub.